# How to do Fixed size async calls on java-ee

Tags: jakarta-ee, concurrency, java-8

I have a call which does a Async method call. The method `createRes` is  `javax.ejb.Asynchronous`.

```
for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
    Future<Res> result = utils.createRes(stuff);
}
```

I want there to be maximum of 3 calls called on `createRes`. So the idea is when ever a single `Future` completes it should go for the next one. So its almost like ExecutorService.

As for this code, it should call `utils.createRes` 1st 3 times one after the other without blocking. But 4th call should not be made until one of the previous `Future`s are *DONE*.

Note : I'm using J2EE so the external threading services are not advice to be used.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when the 4th call comes in?

Comment: @SteveC I updated the text. Tx

Comment: Are you trying to throttle access to a service?

Comment: Yes. my 'createRes' is calling external API. This api want to have maximum of 3 calls at a given point.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this kind of problem before by setting up a JMS queue and restricting the size of the thread pool used by the associated MDB.

If you only have a single node system then these days you could use the Java EE [javax.enterprise.concurrent. ManagedExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/concurrent/ManagedExecutorService.html) in a similar way, again configuring the thread pool size of the provided service in your application server.

Either way, you're just submitting tasks to some kind of queue and throttling it by restricting the thread pool size.

Answer (score 0):

So to clarify, you’re essentially trying to mimic an ExecutorService, ie control the number of threads available for a job. Please correct me if I’m wrong.

From the code snippet it’s a bit hard to see the best way forward since the local variable `result` is just assigned 100 times and then discarded. But assuming you’re doing something with `result`, you could:

1. If you’re on EE 6, define your own pool of Stateless session beans, and annotate your `utils` object as `@Stateless` and also mark it with `@Pool(value=“myPool”)`. You also need to add a pool definition in your standalone.xml and set its size to three. So whenever you call `utils#createRes` it can only ever go to one of three beans.
2. Create a class in between `util` and its client which will manage the number of async calls. Most probably it will need to synchronise on some counter to make sure you never have more than three active worker threads, so you take a performance hit because of the locking but you’d have one anyway with an ExecutorService.
3. Probably not an option, but for completeness I’ll add it: upgrade to EE7 and use and ExecutorService :-D

There’s a good write up of the details behind option 1 here: http://www.mastertheboss.com/javaee/ejb-3/custom-pool-configuration-for-your-ejbs-on-jboss-as-7-wildfly